# clojure lein jar clash resolution process

Tags: jar, clojure, version, leiningen, name-clash

I have created a new project with

```
lein new jar-clash-test
cd jar-clash-test/
```

I have put the following in project.clj

```
(defproject jar-clash-test "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.0"]
                 [io.pedestal/pedestal.service "0.1.2"]
                 ...]
  :main ^{:skip-aot true} jar-clash-test.core
)
```

I have put the following in jar-clash-test/src/jar_clash_test/core.clj

```
(ns jar-clash-test.core
  (:require [io.pedestal.service.http :as bootstrap]))
```

When I run this with

```
lein repl
```

I get the following error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such var: content-type/content-type-response, compiling:(io/pedestal/service/http/ring_middlewares.clj:46:3)
```

When I look at:

```
/.m2/repository/io/pedestal/pedestal/0.1.2/pedestal.service-0.1.2/io/ring_middlewares.clj
```

On line 46 I see:

```
  (leave-interceptor ::content-type-interceptor content-type/content-type-response opts))
```

Which is defined in the requirements as:

```
[ring.middleware.content-type :as content-type]
```

Which means it is trying to bring in the ring-middleware jar.

My hypothesis is that there is a jar version clash for the ring middleware implementation.

This is based on:

1. [compojure "1.1.3"] [has a dependency][2](https://clojars.org/compojure/versions/1.1.3) on [ring/ring-core "1.1.5"]
2. [io.pedestal/pedestal.service "0.1.2"] [has a dependency on][3](https://clojars.org/io.pedestal/pedestal.service/versions/0.1.2) [ring/ring-core "1.2.0-beta1"]

When I look at:

```
/.m2/repository/ring/ring-core/1.2.0-beta1/ring-core-1.2.0-beta1/ring/middleware/content_type.clj
```

The function

```
(defn content-type-response
```

exists. When I look at:

```
/.m2/repository/ring/ring-core/1.1.5/ring-core-1.1.5/ring/middleware/content_type.clj
```

The function doesn't exist.

My question is - how do I know which version lein has picked up? I can 'assume' it has picked up the earlier one - but how I can know for certain?

My second question is - how can I guarantee which one lein will pick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say `lein classpath` to get a printout of the computed value of the classpath for your project. Earlier jars win. Another approach: examine the value of `(System/getProperty "java.class.path")` at the REPL.

If you want to pick a version of an indirect dependency by hand, make it direct, that is, add it to your `project.clj`; this entry will then override the dependencies' choices in the context of this project. Alternatively, you could add `:exclusions` to all but one of your dependencies which cause the indirect dependency to be pulled in.

Comment: For a quick and easy look at what dependencies are being loaded from where, use `lein deps :tree`.

Comment: I have had lein use a version used by an indirect dependency rather than a version I specifically requested (I asked for clojure 1.4, one of my dependencies asks for 1.3, 1.3 got used at runtime). The only reliable way to ensure a specific lib is used is lein pedantic and exclusions